# Bound norm of a product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition

Let $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{q_1}$, $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{q_2}$ be row vectors. Denote the $[2 \times (q_1 + q_2)]$  dimensional matrix \begin{equation} 
X = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Assume we have a real, symmetric $[(q_1+q_2)\times(q_1+q_2)]$ matrix $S$ that is a positive definite with bounded eigenvalues. I would like to bound the squared norm of the following product \begin{equation}
||(XSX^T)^{-1/2}X||^2 \leq \ (??)
 \end{equation}
where $(\cdot)^{-1/2}$ denotes the square root matrix of the inverse. $||\cdot||$ is the induced $\ell^2$-norm/spectral norm.

My guess is that this should be bound by something proportional to $1/\lambda_{min}(S)$.
I tried using the spectral decomposition for $S$ together with the block form but the inverse square root always throws me off. Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick upper bound. Since $S\ge\lambda_\min(S)I$, we have
$$
XSX^T
\ge X(\lambda_\min(S)I)X^T
=\lambda_\min(S)XX^T
$$
and in turn
\begin{aligned}
\|(XSX^T)^{-1/2}X\|^2
&\le\|(XSX^T)^{-1/2}\|^2\|X\|^2\\
&=\|(XSX^T)^{-1}\|\|X\|^2\\
&\le\|\lambda_\min(S)^{-1}(XX^T)^{-1}\|\|X\|^2\\
&=\lambda_\min(S)^{-1}\frac{\max\left(\|x_1\|_2^2,\|x_2\|_2^2\right)}{\min\left(\|x_1\|_2^2,\|x_2\|_2^2\right)}.\\
\end{aligned}